# [service]-[stage]-custom-resource-apigw-cw-roleのランタイムを変更する方法

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

「AWS LambdaでのNode.js 16のサポート終了について」という通知を受信しました。
「Node.js 16の関数をNode.js 20にアップブレード」してくださいという内容でした。

調べたところ、CodePipelineでデプロイしたとき、「[service]-[stage]-custom-resource-apigw-cw-role」というLambdaが生成されており、Lambdaのコンソール上で確認すると、「ランタイム」の表示が「Node.js 16.x」となっていたため、この「ランタイム」をNode.js 20に上げる必要があるという通知かと思います。

Serverless Frameworkを使用しており、前回のNode.js 14からNode.js 16に上げたときは、単にこのFWのバージョンを上げるだけで対応したという履歴がありました。
今回GitHubを見てみると、FWは3.37.0でNode.js 20をサポートしたと読める記載があったため、package.jsonには以下のように記述してデプロイしてみました。

```
"dependencies": {
  "serverless": "^3.38.0",
  "serverless-plugin-log-subscription": "^2.1.3",
  以下省略
}
```

しかし、問題のランタイムはNode.js 16のままでした。
自分の調べ方が誤っていたのかと思いますので、どのような調査をすべきか、どのような修正をすべきかについてアドバイスをお願いします。